# Android Honeycomb ListView does not load but no exception either

Tags: android, android-listview, android-3.0-honeycomb

I have the following XML layout:

```
    <LinearLayout 
        android:id="@+id/map_locations_list"
        android:layout_width="300dp"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:layout_marginLeft="8dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
        android:background="@color/black_shadow"
        android:layout_gravity="left">

            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="fill_parent"
                android:orientation="vertical">
                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/location_results_info"
                    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                    android:layout_height="56dp"
                    android:background="@android:color/white"
                    android:text="Stuff goes here"
                    android:padding="10dp"
                />
                <ListView
                    android:id="@+id/locations_view"
                    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
                    android:layout_weight="1.0"
                />
                <TextView
                    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
                    android:text="this is a test" />
            </LinearLayout>
    </LinearLayout>

<fragment class="fragmentClass" 
    android:id="@+id/fragmentId" 
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"/>
```

And the following Java code to load the ListView:

```
String lv_arr[]={"Android","iPhone","BlackBerry","AndroidPeople"};  
ListView locationsLV = (ListView)findViewById(R.id.locations_view);
locationsLV.setAdapter(new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1 , lv_arr));
```

The ListView does not get loaded with any values, but it also does not throw an exception. I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong. I used this example as a basis for my code: http://www.androidpeople.com/android-listview-example

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check this XML and try first and then add other components its may be overllapping of components.............

```
   <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <LinearLayout android:id="@+id/locations_view"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <ListView android:id="@+id/ListView01"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
    </LinearLayout>
```